# Error argument of type 'Item' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. TS2345

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting error with type 'string'. TS2345

> Argument of type 'Item' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string'.  TS2345

```
 filter(resortList:ResortResult[], selectedFilters:SelectedFilters) {
    return resortList
      .filter(resort => {
        let roomTypes = resort.available.flat().map(room => room.roomType);
        let activities = resort.activities;
        let hasRoomType = selectedFilters["room"].some(
          (rt:Item)=> roomTypes.indexOf(rt) > -1
        );
        let hasActivity = selectedFilters["activity"].some(
          (act:Item) => ((activities.indexOf(act.value)) > -1)
        );
        return !(
          (selectedFilters["area"].length === 0 ||
            selectedFilters["area"].indexOf(resort.city) > -1) &&
          // (selectedFilters["views"].length === 0 ||
          //   selectedFilters["views"].indexOf(resort.city) > -1) &&
          (selectedFilters["activity"].length === 0 || hasActivity) &&
          (selectedFilters["room"].length === 0 || hasRoomType)
        );
      })
      .map(resort => {
        return resort.propertyCode;
      });
  }
```

How can I fix this error with react-typescript? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like you are using typescript. Typescript is a strongly-typed language, meaning that typically you have to define the datatype for a variable before you can use it. This also means that you can only set a variable to the type that it is assigned.

What this error is saying is that you are trying to assign a value that is not a string to a variable where the type is "string". More specifically, it looks like you are trying to assign a whole object (of type "Item") to a variable with the type "string".

You need to check your code and make sure that you are not trying to assign the wrong datatype somewhere. In the small code snippet that you gave, it's a bit difficult to see where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a different value to a variable as you cannot assign a string to all of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to assign a type to an array callback, like `(rt:Item) =>` and `(act:Item) =>`, that's a sign that some type is either missing or incorrect higher up in the chain.  The callback will get the correct type automatically if the array itself has the correct type.

It seems like the error is most likely in your `indexOf` calls, though it's hard to know for sure without seeing your types for `ResortResult` and `SelectedFilters`.  You are checking that `roomTypes` contains an element `rt` which is an `Item`.  If `roomTypes` is an array of `string` then you would need to check `roomTypes.indexOf(rt.value)` instead of `roomTypes.indexOf(rt)`.

If it is in fact an array of `Item`, you might have confusing results because `indexOf` is checking for strict equality.  That is, it's checking that you have literally the same object instance in both places.

This code passes all type checks, but it might not match your actual types:

```
interface Item {
    value: string;
}

interface ResortResult {
    available: {roomType: string}[][];
    activities: string[];
    propertyCode: string;
    city: string;
}

interface SelectedFilters {
    room: Item[];
    activity: Item[];
    area: string[];
}

 function filter(resortList: ResortResult[], selectedFilters: SelectedFilters) {
    return resortList
      .filter(resort => {
        let roomTypes = resort.available.flat().map(room => room.roomType);
        let activities = resort.activities;
        let hasRoomType = selectedFilters["room"].some(
          (rt) => roomTypes.indexOf(rt.value) > -1
        );
        let hasActivity = selectedFilters["activity"].some(
          (act) => ((activities.indexOf(act.value)) > -1)
        );
        return !(
          (selectedFilters["area"].length === 0 ||
            selectedFilters["area"].indexOf(resort.city) > -1) &&
          // (selectedFilters["views"].length === 0 ||
          //   selectedFilters["views"].indexOf(resort.city) > -1) &&
          (selectedFilters["activity"].length === 0 || hasActivity) &&
          (selectedFilters["room"].length === 0 || hasRoomType)
        );
      })
      .map(resort => {
        return resort.propertyCode;
      });
  }
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WPjyYN)